# Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have suddenly started hitting Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp in Vue Js. I am fairly new to Js and have just started with Vue applications. I tried the various solutions that were mentioned in the Git and stackoverflow but they have not worked. Can someone help me out.

To give some context, the issue suddenly appeared without having made much of a change. The code is working when it was in the state earlier but making any change in the components even modifying the css has started causing the issue.
Based on what I read about the issue, it is supposed to be controlled by the webpack.prod.conf.js (Attached mine below). Incase any other info is needed please let me know.

```
"use strict";
const path = require("path");
const utils = require("./utils");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const config = require("../config");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const baseWebpackConfig = require("./webpack.base.conf");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

const env = require("../config/prod.env");

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    module: {
        rules: utils.styleLoaders({
            sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
            extract: true,
            usePostCSS: true
        })
    },
    devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath("js/[name].[chunkhash].js"),
        chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath("js/[id].[chunkhash].js")
    },
    plugins: [
        // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": env
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            },
            sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
            parallel: true
        }),
        // extract css into its own file
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: utils.assetsPath("css/[name].[contenthash].css"),
            // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
            // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
            // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`,
            // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
            allChunks: true
        }),
        // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
        // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
        new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap ?
                { safe: true, map: { inline: false } } :
                { safe: true }
        }),
        // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
        // you can customize output by editing /index.html
        // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: config.build.index,
            template: "index.html",
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
                    // more options:
                    // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
            },
            // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
            chunksSortMode: "dependency"
        }),
        // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        // enable scope hoisting
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        // split vendor js into its own file
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            async: false,
            minChunks(module) {
                // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
                return (
                    module.resource &&
                    /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
                    module.resource.indexOf(path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules")) === 0
                );
                // return module.context && module.context.includes("node_modules");
            }
        }),
        // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
        // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
        // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "app",
            async: "vendor-async",
            children: true,
            minChunks: 3
        }),
        // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
        // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "manifest",
            async: false,
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),

        // copy custom static assets
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../static"),
            to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
            ignore: [".*"]
        }])
    ]
});

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
    const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
            asset: "[path].gz[query]",
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: new RegExp(
                "\\.(" + config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join("|") + ")$"
            ),
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    );
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
        .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

The entry points are missing in the configuration, i.e. you are not informing webpack from where the application should start.
Also this issue is happening because you have mentioned `vendor`
please refer [this link](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)

Comment: Sorry if its silly, I am new to this but can you elaborate on the entry part. Which file should be specified as entry? This was not there in the beginning also but then the code was running fine what do you think caused it to break?